# Copy files & folders from a network location using a text file containing the directories

Tags: batch-file

Hi All as the title suggests i need to copy all the files in a given directory.

I have a txt files containing a list of directories and the files that i need to access are on a network

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
for /f usebackq delims=" %%a in ("my folder list.txt") do xcopy "%%~a" "X:\destination\folder" /iehkoy
```

For use on the command line always use one percent sign: `%a`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work - `/mir` does a mirror backup and deletes files that no longer exist in the source folder tree, so change the switches if you don't want that behaviour.

foo.txt should contain lines like the following

\\server1\share\files
c:\source\files_folder
c:\users\jack\desktop
\\server2\share\music-folder

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "foo.txt" ') do robocopy "%%a" "d:\target\your\preferred\path\" /mir
```

This is an example for a network path.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "foo.txt" ') do robocopy "%%a" "\\server\share\path\" /mir
```

Comment: include "delims=" and double quotes and it's close.

Comment: @foxidrive don't know cmd too well (using bash all the time i could) - could you please provide full answer so i could delete mine?

Comment: hmmm im a bit lost.. im new to batch files so i dont know all the intricate syntaxs to be ammended. is there a program that does this for you hahah.

Comment: Erm.. well, 'foo.txt' is text file with names you mentioned, 'your\prefered\path' is destination directory you want to copy to. Type is standard command that displays contents of text files, then 'for' iterates through results of type and executes robocopy (one of copy programs) for each of them. Don't know what else to say.